# Host return in power usage 0 despite the Host is powered ON

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli, vcenter

im trying to parse our Vcenter in Powershell using PowerCli but one host is returning in stat "power.power.usage" 0 even the host is powerred on and it is returned .

#my script is below

```
$Report = @()

$stat1 = "power.power.average"
$stat2 = "power.energy.summation"
$stat3 = "power.powercap.average"

foreach ($entity in $entities)
{
    $name = $entity.name

    $poweraverage = (Get-Stat -Entity $entity  -Stat $stat1 -Realtime -MaxSamples 1 ).Value
    $energySum = (Get-Stat -Entity $entity -Stat $stat2  -Realtime -MaxSamples 1).Value
    $PowerCap = (Get-Stat -Entity $entity -Stat $stat3  -Realtime -MaxSamples 1).Value
    $LastAnalysis = (Get-Stat -Entity $entity -Stat $stat1  -Realtime -MaxSamples 1).timestamp

    $Report += [pscustomobject]@{
        TimeStamp                          = $LastAnalysis
        Host                               = $name
        CurrentPowerUsage                  = $poweraverage
        MaximumAllowedPowerUsage           = $PowerCap 
        TotalenergyUsedSinceLastStatsReset = $energySum
    }
}

$Report
```

outpout:

```
TimeStamp                          : 1/28/2022 1:59:40 PM
Host                               : host IP address 
CurrentPowerUsage                  : 0
MaximumAllowedPowerUsage           : 0
TotalenergyUsedSinceLastStatsReset : 0

TimeStamp                          : 1/28/2022 2:00:00 PM
Host                               : host IP address 
CurrentPowerUsage                  : 195
MaximumAllowedPowerUsage           : 0
TotalenergyUsedSinceLastStatsReset : 3955
```

Note : the host return PoweredON  om get-Vmhost

Comment: Please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70893931/edit) your post properly.

Comment: i did , thank you

Comment: Is the information about the other host correct/expected?

Comment: yes , but almost 60% ov hosts return 0, some of them are same Gen, version , serial  but they are not returning the same information.